# Understanding Newman's proof of the prime number theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

I am trying to understand [D.J. Newman's proof of the prime number theorem, as presented by D. Zagier](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Zagier.pdf). I am not too familiar with analysis, and so there are some things I don't understand.

1. In (III), what does Zagier mean by "$\theta(x)$ changes by $O(\log x)$ if $x$ changes by $O(1)$?" I know the definition of Big O notation, but not what this grammatical construction means.
2. In (V), I am having trouble parsing the integral
   $$ \int_1^\infty \frac{d \theta(x)}{x^s}. $$
   What does the notation $d \theta(x)$ mean? Is $\theta(x)$ the variable of integration in some sense? If so, how? (This may be a naive question.)
3. In the lower bound for $\theta(x)$ (on p. 707), in the bounds for the first summation -- $x^{1-\epsilon} \leq p \leq xx$ -- is $xx$ a typo, supposed to be $x$, or is it correct? If it's correct, why is the first inequality true?
4. I don't understand why the lower bound for $\theta(x)$,
   $$ \theta(x) \geq (1-\epsilon) \log x (\pi(x) + O(x^{1-\epsilon})), $$
   is good enough. As $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, $O(x^{1-\epsilon})$ tends to $O(x)$, and based on my interpretation of the previous summations, I expect this error term to be negative. Since $\pi(x) \leq x$, I basically don't understand why this is saying more than that $\theta(x) \geq 0$.

Thank you!

Comment: For #$1$,
$\theta(x+a)-\theta(x)=\sum_{x\leq p\leq {x+a}}\ln(p)<a\ln(x+a)<c\ln(x)$, for some constant c

Comment: For #$2$, its a stieltjes integral, read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: For #$3$, Yes it is a typo

Comment: For #$4$, If you're not comfortable doing it this way, try summation by parts, you should get the result pretty fast,
 $$\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\n\in \text{ S}}}f(n)g(n)=f([x])\sum_{\substack{ n\leq x \\ n\in \text{S}}}g(n)-\sum_{n\leq x-1}(\sum_{\substack{k\leq n \\ k\in \text{S}}}g(k))(f(n+1)-f(n))$$
Let $\text{S}$ be the set of primes less then or equal to x, then let $f(n)=\ln(n)$

Comment: @Ethan, why not roll these comments up into an answer?

Comment: @Ethan: Thank you very much for the answers! Would you be willing to answer further questions about this proof, e.g., through email or chat? I keep running into roadblocks of this type, where it would be very nice to have some help getting unstuck.

Comment: @NickThomas Not sure how much I can help, but you can talk to me on the chat here.

Comment: Hi Nick and Ethan, I am working on the same proof by Zagier. This post was very helpful for me. I encountered the same problems but i am still not clear about the 4th one. I couldn't understand, what is the summation by parts and how does it help us to overcome the ambiguity caused by $\Bbb O(x^{1-\epsilon})$. Please elaborate this equation and its link to the 4th doubt. I will be very thankful to you.